# Add a safe area to List after hiding the navigation bar in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

I want to customize the navigation bar, but the refresh control is covered by the custom navigation bar after hiding the navigation. How can I adjust the position of the refresh control?

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HomeNavigationBarView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EmptyView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Hello, world!")
                    }
                }
                .listStyle(.insetGrouped)
                .refreshable {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Here is my custom navbar

```swift
struct HomeNavigationBarView<Content: View>: View {
    
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            content()
            HStack {
                Image("logo")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
            }
            .frame(height: insetTop(), alignment: .bottom)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(.red.opacity(0.1))
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}

private func insetTop() -> CGFloat {
    
    let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
    let window = windowScene?.windows.first
    return window?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0       // 20或47
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way of adding safe area in iOS15+ perfectly solves this problem

```swift
List {

}
.safeAreaInset(edge: .top, spacing: 0) {
    Rectangle()
        .fill(.clear)
        .frame(height: insetTop() + 44)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding should be there in List *.padding(.top, insetTop())* to fix position of refresh control.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            HomeNavigationBarView {
                List {
                    NavigationLink {
                        EmptyView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Hello, world!")
                    }
                }
                .padding(.top, insetTop())
                .refreshable {
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a simple padding problem, I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

My solution simple easy to hiding navigation after pull refresh by set padding when isRefreshing like this :

```
@State private var isRefreshing = false
private let diffSafeHeightArea = 60
   ScrollView {
      VStack {

      }
      .padding(.top, isRefreshing ? -diffSafeHeightArea : 0)
    }
    .refreshable {
      isRefreshing = true
      viewModel.pullToRefresh {
            isRefreshing = false
      }
    }
```